# Find value of input element

Tags: clojurescript

I thought this would be pretty straight-forward but it seems like I'm overlooking something.

```
(ns main.core
  (:require [dommy.core :refer-macros [sel sel1]]))

(sel1 :#my-input) => #<[object HTMLInputElement]>

(.value (sel1 :#my-input)) 
=> #<TypeError: document.querySelector(...).value is not a function>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ClojureScript we have two special forms for interop with JavaScript: `.` and `.-`.

`.` should be used to call methods of objects and `.-` should be used to access properties (including functions as a value). If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/Prismatic/dommy/blob/master/src/dommy/core.cljs#L27) of the `value` function in the Dommy library you'll see that it uses the `.-` special form.

Take a look here: https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Differences-from-Clojure#host-interop

This cheatsheet is also useful: https://himera.herokuapp.com/index.html

Comment: Certainly a much much thinner wrapper around `.-value` than I expected.

Answer (score 2):

While I'm not 100% why `.value` isn't working, the following works splendidly:

```
(ns main.core
  (:require [dommy.core :as dommy :refer-macros [sel sel1]]))

(sel1 :#my-input) => #<[object HTMLInputElement]>

(dommy/value (sel1 :#my-input)) 
=> "my-input-value"
```